# recursive call, stackoverflow execption?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am writing a snake game in Java. As part of the game I have to randomly allocate a token that the snake will "eat" to increment the score. So here I am using a random generator, but in order not to generate a token within the body of the snake, I'm using this logic:

```
token_x = (tokenPositionGenerator.nextInt(40)*10)+30;
token_y = (tokenPositionGenerator.nextInt(40)*10)+30;

// check if token is generated in place of snake head

if (token_x == head_x || token_y == head_y)
{
    generateNewToken();
}

// check if token is generated within rest of snakes body
for (int i=0;i<tail_x.size();i++){
    if (token_x == tail_x.get(i) || token_y == tail_y.get(i))
    {
        generateNewToken();
    }
}
```

- `head_x`, `head_y` is (x,y) position of snake head.
- `tail_x` and `tail_y` are lists containing (x,y) positions of tail objects.
- `generateNewToken()` is recursively calling the method.

Now when a token is generated, within the snake's body, I get a stackoverflow exception. Not sure how to avoid that.

Any thoughts on this, maybe I could achieve with a different logic?

Comment: To avoid the stack overflow there must be some condition that will return from the recursive method without another recursive call.

Comment: Can we see the `generateNewToken()` method?

Comment: that is the whole generateNewToken method, just without public void declaration.

Comment: Please post all your code, I for example can not find a reference to `head_x` nor `head_y`.

Comment: @skiwi : Sorry its a lot of code, I tried editing the question though to add more info.

Comment: Please see my answer below... your checks seem to be wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you rewrite your code and solve the problem without recursion - as it is not needed here.

If I understood you right, you a generating tokens at randomized positions and check if the snake (head or tail) is already occupying this location.

Here is how I would try to solve your task

- Generate a random token
- Check if head or tail positions match the tokens position
- if yes, re-generate the token (while-loop?)
- if no, you are finished

hmm another question: are your checks correct? What would you check to see if head and token are at the same position in x/y-ccordinates? At the moment you are checking if either the x-coordinate is the same (head and token are on the same row) or the y-coordinate. But both must match, or? So I would replace the conditional or `||` by a conditional and `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a base case that exits the recursive method. Without a base case your method will recursively call itself and never terminate until the machine becomes overwhelmed. I suspect your `head` check is the base case.

Try this:

```
if (token_x == head_x || token_y == head_y)
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't exit the method does it? I believe that that will exit the if statement.

Comment: I actually want to recall the method if (token_x == head_x)

Comment: @codeNinja `return` is a reserved word in java that methods look for as a signal to exit a method. In the case of void methods, you may specify an empty return statement.

Comment: Whoever minused one, please explain why.

Comment: @ssayyed When is your generateToken() method finished? How are you determining being done?

Comment: nothing specifically, I thought recalling the method would result in new values of token_x and token_y, and if those values don't meeting the conditions of the if statements, the method should finish executing?

Comment: @ssayyed In that case, recursion may not be the best option. You can write a general method that continues generating tokens using a `while` loop until your logical conditions are met. Then you can return the `Token` object and be finished.